# change numbers to number with separator in math statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

I want convert a math statement to math statement with separator.

For example i have this statement:

```
(2000+1000.33+33)*20000.33
```

And want convert to this:

```
(2,000+1,000.33+33)*20,000.33
```

How can i convert this statement in JavaScript?

Comment: you can convert your statement to a string and use regex to insert the commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = (2000+1000.33+33)*20000.33;
x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

Comment: you need to convert the expression to a string in order to use replace()

Comment: @PDN : toString() didn't worked for me. It return 60667600.998900004 when convert my statement to string.